# What is the difference between these two data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, r-forestplot

I have got two data. I am using [r](/questions/tagged/r) for [forestplot](/questions/tagged/forestplot).
 
Data one:

```
                           coef       lower       upper 
Males vs Female          0.04088551  0.03483956  0.04693145
85 vs 65 years          -0.05515741 -0.06508088 -0.04523394
Charlsons Medium vs Low -0.03833060 -0.04727946 -0.02938173
Charlsons High vs Low   -0.09247572 -0.12020001 -0.06475144
```

Data two:

```
                       ..1   mean  lower  upper
1                         A 1.4194 0.8560 2.3536
2                         B 0.6574 0.2333 1.8523
3                         C 0.7751 0.4012 1.4973
4                         D 1.0831 0.6587 1.7811
5                         E 1.3362 0.6559 2.7221
```

1. I need my data two should be looked like data one(not in value). The data two is [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe), what do you think is data one?
2. In data one there is no reference for row number but in data two. I need the row number to be gone. 
3. I need data two as a [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix). But if I convert it as a matrix, these are the row reference which gets considered as a column while I am doing forest plot. 
Can you please suggest anything?

Comment: You may check for yourself with `class(Data.one)`. Actually there are never row numbers, we're saying row names (they are class `"character"`), which default to consecutive numbers if not set. Delete them with `rownames(Data.one) <- NULL`, set them with `rownames(Data.one) <- c("A", "B", ...)`. `colnames(.)` accordingly. Your weird `..1` column in `Data.two` is just an ordinary column, but you just realized that anyway :) `rownames(Dat.two) <- Dat.two$..1; Dat.two <- Dat.two[-1]` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. It fixed. Great help. I have to convert the data two to matrix. The class of data one was a matrix.  @jay.sf